# Null при выводе

Tags: golang

Две одинаковые функции различаются выводом, первая рабочая, вторая на выводе в место `*model.User` выдает null. Почему так происходит ?

```
func (us *UserStore) FindUserByEmail(email string) *model.User {
    u := &model.User{}
    us.db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?", email).Scan(
        &u.ID,
        &u.Email,
        &u.Password,
        &u.Hash,
        &u.Data,
    )

    return u
}
```

```
func (us *UserStore) FindUserByEmail(email string) (*model.User,error) {
    u := &model.User{}
    if err := us.db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?", email).Scan(
        &u.ID,
        &u.Email,
        &u.Password,
        &u.Hash,
        &u.Data,
    ); err != nil{
        return nil, err
    }

    return u, nil
}
```

Comment: Могу предположить, что  `If the query selects no rows, the *Row's Scan will return ErrNoRows.`, т.е если строка не найдена, то возвращается ошибка ErrNoRows

Comment: Но дело в том что при любом положении вещей получается null если строка найдена или не найдена, как только удаляешь error из retrun или возвращаешь (model.User,error) в место (*model.user, error) все начинает работать как надо

Comment: А что за ошибка?  Можете ее вывести?

Comment: при выводе самой структуры выдает в место нее null. Есть нужно взаимодействовать с каким то полем структуры например `if u.ID > 0`  выдает ошибку                                                                                                                             
 `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:212 (0x8ce484)
        panicmem: panic(memoryError)`

Comment: Нашел в чем причина была при выборке из базы некоторые поля хранившиеся в таблице были null при этом получалась ошибка ```converting NULL to string is unsupported``` . Решил изменением некоторых типов полей в структуре пользователя на ``` *string``` в место ``` string```

Comment: А что за библиотеку вы используете которая работает с БД?

Comment: database/sql и драйвер mysql github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql. Примерно тоже самое получалось и с postgres